# Why adjacent calls of Datatime.now() gives same results on Windows

Tags: python, datetime

**Env:** Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10 64 bits (Home)

**Desc:** Adjacent calls of `datatime.now()` produce same results, like the outputs of the `test_for_loop` and `test_seq_sleep_call` below. Why?

The outputs of other two functions show the it can difference around 0.001 second rather that what some posts said. The official document, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, didn't mention this -or any thing about 'threads safe' , 'asynchronous', neither.

**Test Code:**

```
import datetime
from time import sleep


def get_dt_str():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")


def test_for_loop(loops):
    print(">>> test_for_loop")
    for i in range(loops):
        print(get_dt_str())


def test_for_sleep_loop(loops, inter):
    print(">>> test_for_sleep_loop")
    for i in range(loops):
        print((get_dt_str()))
        sleep(inter)


def test_seq_call():
    print(">>> test_seq_call")
    print(get_dt_str())
    print(get_dt_str())
    print(get_dt_str())
    print(get_dt_str())
    print(get_dt_str())
    print(get_dt_str())


def test_seq_sleep_call(inter):
    print(">>> test_seq_sleep_call")
    print(get_dt_str())
    sleep(inter)
    print(get_dt_str())
    sleep(inter)
    print(get_dt_str())
    sleep(inter)
    print(get_dt_str())
    sleep(inter)
    print(get_dt_str())
    sleep(inter)


loops = 5
inter = 0.0001
test_for_loop(loops)
test_for_sleep_loop(loops,inter)
test_seq_call()
test_seq_sleep_call(inter)
```

Outputs:

```
>>> test_for_loop
2018-05-14 18:17:12.840731
2018-05-14 18:17:12.840731
2018-05-14 18:17:12.840731
2018-05-14 18:17:12.840731
2018-05-14 18:17:12.840731
>>> test_for_sleep_loop
2018-05-14 18:17:12.840731
2018-05-14 18:17:12.855748
2018-05-14 18:17:12.871853
2018-05-14 18:17:12.888597
2018-05-14 18:17:12.905376
>>> test_seq_call
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
>>> test_seq_sleep_call
2018-05-14 18:17:12.921394
2018-05-14 18:17:12.949092
2018-05-14 18:17:12.965107
2018-05-14 18:17:12.981064
2018-05-14 18:17:12.997023
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case on W10 and not on your average Linux environment (e.g. [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3)).

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, the `perf_counter()` is a solution. Thank you ~

Comment: @BramVanroy , yes, on Linux it results differently.